# libGDX How to do a scrollable Home screen

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I whant to get my home screen to be scrollable to left and right.
I use scene2d and it should be like: Credits screen / Singleplayer screen / Multiplayer screen / Options...

I know how to handle Input don't explain this...

Questions:

1. Schould i use for every screen a different Stage?
2. Does it have somting to do with Viewport?
3. If the home screen gets called does it take long to initialise the stage/s
4. If 3 is true, how can i load the while an splash screen is displaying?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your questions:

1. You can, but then the hard part will be a smooth transition between them.
2. If you only use one stage, you could use the viewport for the scroll animation. I would suggest you to use a `ScrollPane` though (see example below).
3. If you don't mess up the implementation, it does not take long.
4. I suggest you to look at the AssetManager: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets

As you can see, there are multiple ways to get such a scrolling screen. I have personal experience using the `ScrollPane` to achieve this solution.
See: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/ScrollPane.html and http://nexsoftware.net/wp/2013/05/09/libgdx-making-a-paged-level-selection-screen/

Comment: Good luck ;) I would really recommend you the last link, I tried it and it looks very smooth! If you like the answer, I would appreciate an upvote or even the acceptance as the best answer :)